# Wordpress assets not accessible anymore

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem following the switch to production server. I no longer have access to images and media in general and some style files.

Yet I modified all the links. A first time with the wp-migrate tool, the second directly from the SQL file. 
I've reset htaccess.
I also checked the rights of folders and files. (I put them at 755 to test). 
Finally, the files have no accents.

My environment:

Wordpress 4.9.8
php 5.6.38
Mysql 5
theme base: https://themeforest.net/item/pheromone-responsive-multiconcept-template/15432549

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Try to access one of those files directly, e.g. an image. It is possible? How is the path? (Example?) Is this path correct?
Are you getting errors in the console, like 404s?

Comment: Can you find out the difference between the still accessible styles files and those you cannot access anymore?

Comment: thanks @jasie for your answer,       The problem start right from the wordpress back office. What is strange is that I have no visual thumbnails but when I copy / paste the address in the browser it works. In front-office, the images are called in different ways with relative paths for some with absolute paths for others; they can be called hard (www.siteurl.com/wp-content/.../pics.jpg) or with functions like: get_permalink (00) or the_post_thumbnail_url () ...
For styles they are called like this get_stylesheet_directory_uri ().Path / style.css or with wordpress function wp_enqueu_style ().

Comment: I wonder if this would not come from a mysql quota problem or a problem of data deserialization...

Comment: Problem solved, it came from the database

Comment: Congrats. Don't miss the opportunity to answer your own question and help others with the same problem as well as collect SO points.